# Touchpad Mouse becoming unresponsive on Thinkpad

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

My mouse (Touchpad) has been unresponsive on my Thinkpad T440p for a few hours now. Updating the driver, rebooting the machine, nothing worked. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you run the troubleshooter? (Control Panel).

Comment: Run Lenovo Diagnostics to see if it can detect a fault, update your BIOS before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Realtek HD Audio Driver seems to be responsible for this!

I uninstalled the Realtek HD Audio from Add/Remove Programs & rebooted the machine & the mouse started working fine. However, after a few minutes, the same problem recurred again. I went to Add/Remove Programs and saw that Realtek HD Audio had reappeared.

This is because Windows 10 updates drivers automatically. To disable this

Go to Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings
Hardware Tab->Device Installation Settings

Choose "No" in the option to automatically download drivers.

I then uninstalled Realtek HD Audio again. Uninstalled Realtek LAN Driver also just to be safe. Went to c:\program files & deleted the Realtek directory. Went to c:\program files (x86) and deleted the Realtek directory there also.

Touchpad is working fine now. Keeping fingers crossed.

Comment: EDIT: I also had to change the permissions of the Realtek directories (32 & 64) bit so that nothing can get installed there.